# Teradata - Nest Aggregate Operations in Case Statement

Tags: teradata, case-statement

I'm getting an error "cannot nest aggregate operations" when trying running script below. I searched other questions with similar titles but they do not address this.

I'm trying to sum data from a period, sum other data from the same period and subtract one from the other. Seems so simple in my head! Can someone help?

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN a.post_ts(DATE) between 1140921 and 1140927 THEN (pnt_amt(DEC (16,0)))   
- sum ((dlr_val*1000)*-1)END) Week 34 
FROM DB.T1 b  
,DB.T2 a 
LEFT JOIN DB.T3 c ON A.OID = C.OID 
WHERE a.lid = b.lid
```

or this:

```
Sel
SUM(CASE WHEN a.post_ts(DATE) between 1140921 and 1140927 THEN (pnt_amt(DEC (16,0)))  
-  SUM(CASE WHEN a.post_ts(DATE) between 1140921 and 1140927 THEN sum ((dlr_val*1000)*-1)END)week_34
 FROM DB.T1 b  
,DB.T2 a 
LEFT JOIN DB.T3 c ON A.OID = C.OID 
WHERE a.lid = b.lid
```

Comment: NOTE: I modified the date range in the second script sample to reflect the same date range in both parts of the query consistent with my intent. DNOETH copied my original script in his response but his response would also need to reflect the same date range in both parts of the query.  
Comment added to assist future readers to understand the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but it's probably like this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN a.post_ts(DATE) BETWEEN 1140921 AND 1140927 THEN (pnt_amt(DEC (16,0))) END  
- SUM((dlr_val*1000)*-1)) Week 34 
FROM DB.T1 b  
,DB.T2 a 
LEFT JOIN DB.T3 c ON A.OID = C.OID 
WHERE a.lid = b.lid
```

or

```
SEL
SUM(CASE WHEN a.post_ts(DATE) BETWEEN 1140921 AND 1140927 THEN (pnt_amt(DEC (16,0))) END) 
-  SUM(CASE WHEN a.post_ts(DATE) BETWEEN 1140202 AND 1140208 THEN (dlr_val*1000)*-1 END)week_34
 FROM DB.T1 b  
,DB.T2 a 
LEFT JOIN DB.T3 c ON A.OID = C.OID 
WHERE a.lid = b.lid
```

Btw, instead of `dlr_val*1000)*-1` you can simply use `-dlr_val*1000)` and you better switch to `DATE '2014-02-02'` instead of `1140202`, it's much easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you! All I needed was another "end" - 
Thanks for clarifying the sign change statement, I always thought my code was a little clunky. As for the dates, I'm used to using the format I used but I understand it is easier for others to read a standard date format. Thanks again! Worked perfectly.